# Как настроить Live Server на синхронизацию нескольких браузеров?

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, visual-studio-code

Live Server работает только с одним браузером (может и не только с одним, просто это я не знаю как настроить расширение). Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли как-то настроить Live Server на синхронизацию нескольких браузеров или для этого нужно устанавливать другое расширение/другую программу (типа browser-sync...)

Comment: ну так работает же , он показывает что соединение установлено в порт 5500 вот и подключайте все браузеры в localhost:5500

Comment: С этим разобрался. Не знаете, можно ли каким-то образом подключить к этому соединению другие устройства?

Comment: вот с этим у меня у самого проблемы - по началу live  reload работал офигенно а потом и до сих пор нет ... что я только ни делал ...писал уже "на марс" ноль помощи ... в общем не знаю

Comment: Просто тут, как я надумал, нужно browser-sync устанавливать

Comment: и его я тоже использовал - тоже не долго - сломался он потом - и не пашет

Comment: Хах, проблема на проблеме.

Comment: ну может у вас по другому будет ... попробуйте установить npm - gulp - ну и сам sync

Comment: Хорошо. Попробую